# Вывести результат функции PHP до её вызова

Tags: php

Вопрос такой: есть ли способ, с которым я бы мог задать параметры в функцию после `<h1>123</h1>` , а результат бы вывелся перед этими цифрами?

```
<?php
//параметры функции должны задаться после 123, а результат должен появится перед
        $inventory = [
        "#1" => ["sku" => "81231846523248", "name" => "Spilvens", "price" => "12.99", "group" => "12"],
        "#2" => ["sku" => "84751530004684", "name" => "Pleds", "price" => "24.99", "group" => "12"],
        ];

        function discountSimple($discount){

            $inventory = &$GLOBALS['inventory'];
            $inventory["#1"] += ["dprice" => $inventory["#1"]["price"] * $discount];

        }
        echo $inventory["#1"]["dprice"];
?>

<h1>123</h1>

<?php

        discountSimple(0.6);

?>
```

Comment: ээмм.. написать вызов перед цифрами? `<h1><?php echo discountSimple(0.6); ?>123</h1>`

Comment: @Lexx918 К сожалению не так всё просто. Например, если после цифр "123" будет форма для введения параметров, а результат надо будет вывести до "123". Реально ли такое сделать?

Comment: Для динамики php не подходит, javascript в помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наркомания ...

```
$inventory = [
    "#1" => ["sku" => "81231846523248", "name" => "Spilvens", "price" => "12.99", "group" => "12"],
    "#2" => ["sku" => "84751530004684", "name" => "Pleds", "price" => "24.99", "group" => "12"],
];

function discountSimple($discount){

    $inventory = &$GLOBALS['inventory'];
    $inventory["#1"] += ["dprice" => $inventory["#1"]["price"] * $discount];

}

$foo = '%s<h1>123</h1>';

discountSimple(0.6);
echo sprintf($foo, $inventory["#1"]["dprice"]);
```